# What's causing these errors?: "Configuration file "/home/username/.config/kio_httprc" not writable. Please contact your system administrator."

Tags: debian, kde

Every hour or so I'm getting these error messages on my Debian10/KDE machine:

> kio_http - KDialog
>
> Configuration file "/home/username/.config/kio_httprc" not writable.
> Please contact your system administrator.

It's always more than one of those at once (sometimes with a few seconds in between) and it's playing the (loud) notification sound even though I have disabled all notification sounds in KDE's notification settings (but that's a separate issue I guess). Maybe firejail is part of why this error occurs. I think it's either because of the dolphin file explorer or more likely Firefox-esr.

I'd like to know what's trying to write to kio_httprc and why, whether and how to allow or prevent that and if that's a bug in KDE.

I already tried `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep kio_http` but there's no entry except for a `kio_http_cache_` one.

Comment: What does `lsof | grep kio_httprc` show?

Comment: Nothing. Only `...kio_http_` shows lots of entries.

Comment: If the permissions are wrong, have you tried resetting them?

Comment: The permissions of the kio_httprc file? They look alright and are set to rw for my user. Haven't reset them. Maybe firejail (or apparmor) is blocking access to the file.

Comment: I bet you're right.